# ROW_NUMBER() doesnt count right on timestamp

Tags: sql, netezza

I always thought ROW_NUMBER() counts every row +1, but with my timestamp data it doesnt work.

```
ID       TIME
1     2017-05-29 21:08:51.393401
1     2017-05-29 21:08:51.393401
1     2017-01-03 09:37:31.30511
1     2017-01-03 09:37:31.30511
...

 WITH CTE AS( select ID,TIME, ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER
BY TIME) AS TEST from XY )
```

RESULT

```
   ID       TIME                          TEST
    1     2017-05-29 21:08:51.393401       1
    1     2017-05-29 21:08:51.393401       1
    1     2017-01-03 09:37:31.30511        2
    1     2017-01-03 09:37:31.30511        2
    ...
```

The desired result should be 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on...

Edit: to solve the problem, select distinct. 
But perhaps someone can reproduce the fact on a Netezza and confirm, that it´s not working as it should.

Comment: I consider this a bug. You are right, `ROW_NUMBER` should indeed number the rows continually and choose rows arbitrarily in case the `ORDER BY` clause doesn't suffice. The result you are getting looks like `DENSE_RANK` instead. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Oh i forgot it, Netezza

Comment: Okay. I've added the tag for you.

Comment: Thxs. Is there a "workaround" for this problem?

Comment: @HellaF10 . . . Are you sure the `id`s are the same?  I doubt this is a bug in Netezza and more likely unexpected data.

Comment: On a side note: Maybe it's just your sample data, but ... Don't call a column `ID` when it's not uniquely identifying a single row in the table as its name suggests. Even in an example.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Netezza. The result you are getting looks like `DENSE_RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`.

You should be able to circumvent the bug by extending the `ORDER BY` clause with a random number, so the DBMS picks one row arbirarily on a tie on time, as it is supposed to do.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT id, time, ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time, RANDOM()) AS TEST 
  FROM xy 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY id, test;
```

Comment: I think the SQL Extension Kit isnt installed on the Netezza, Can´t find the MT_RANDOM()-Function.  Function 'MT_RANDOM()' does not exist
 Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
 You may need to add explicit typecasts

Comment: Sorry, I saw this myself and replaced `MT_RANDOM` with the built-in `RANDOM`. But my edit was too late for you it seems :-) Please try with `RANDOM()`.

Comment: Thxs for your replie, but it´s the same result. 1,1,2,2. Perhaps it matters, that the ID´s are varchar?

Comment: @HellaF10: Then Gordon may be right. The IDs look the same, but they are not. Pick two result rows where the ID looks equal, than use part of it like in `select distinct id from mytable where id like '%A43C31%' order by id` and check whether you are getting more than one row for the ID. You can use the `ASCII` function to see individual bytes in the strings.

Comment: how exactly? I tryed it with the first 5 letters, `like '%...%'`, but i just get one result. When i use `ascii(ID)` i get for every field the same result.

Comment: `ASCII` tells you the binary code for the first character in the string you give it, so give it the single characters. Use `ascii(substr(id, position, 1))` for every position in the string: `select ascii(substr(id, 1, 1)) as c1, ascii(substr(id, 2, 1)) as c2, ...`.

Comment: Oops, I just found the `UNICODES` function, that gives you the codes for all characters in the string. Use that instead. Here is the docs on string functions: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_char_funcs.html.

Comment: Thank you very much @thorsten-kettner. I used the ascii and the unicodes function to check for differences on the ID, but found nothing. The ID´s are the same, no hidden characters or something. Perhaps someone on a Netezza can check the issue and confirm this fact...

Answer (score 1):

try like below by removing  partition by id

```
 WITH CTE AS (
  select ID,TIME, ROW_NUMER() OVER (ORDER  BY TIME) AS TEST from XY 
             ) select  * from cte
```

Comment: Can´t use it, because i have to check this on some other ID´s too.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe that this is a bug in Netezza.  That is possible, but I would first explore whether the `id`s are *really* the same.

For instance, if `id` is a string and ends in a space, then this will return "1":

```
with t as (
      select '1' as x union all
      select '1 '
     )
select *, row_number() over (partition by x order by x)
from t;
```

There are other reasons why values might look the same.

If `id` is an integer (or numeric), then what-you-see-is-what-you-get, so that would suggest a bug.

Comment: They are the same. Perhaps it matters, that the ID´s are seperated by '|'? Like 231|12|A43C31?

Comment: @HellaF10 . . . What matters is that the ids are not numbers, they are strings.  What you are seeing as the same are probably not the same -- hidden characters, leading or trailing spaces, similar characters in different character sets.

Comment: @HellaF10 . . . You have to fix the data.  The database is (presumably) producing correct results.  It is the data that has an issue.

Comment: I don´t think so, but i´m not sure. How can i check, if there are hidden character? Tryed it with ascii(ID), get for all ID´s the same result...and thxs for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue, Add Partition on time by converting it to varchar datatype, try below

WITH CTE AS( select ID,TIME, ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, TO_VARCHAR(TIME) ORDER
BY TIME) AS TEST from XY ) e,